# How to read data from resful service in SL app?

Tags: rest, silverlight-4.0

I tried to get data from a restful service in SL app. Here is my testing code in SL app:

public void getService()
  {
      Uri serviceURI = new Uri("http://Mysite/Mywcservice/myTest.json?Id1=10&id2=2");
      WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
      proxy.OpenReadCompleted += new penReadCompletedEventHandler(proxy_OpenReadCompleted);
      proxy.OpenReadAsync(serviceURI);
   }

void proxy_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     var myListData = new List();
     Stream stream = e.Result;
     XmlReader response = XmlReader.Create(stream);
     while (response.Read() == true)  //error here
        {
           if (response.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
             {
                MyListData.Add(response.Name);
             }
            }
        }
     this.listBox1.ItemsSource = lstFeed;
}

But I get error on code while (response.Read() == true). It said:
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're using XmlReader to parse a json response.  Or, that's what it looks like to me.